# Keras 2.2.4 with TensorFlow 1.4.1 crashing GPU instances

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, version, nvidia

What is the minimum TensorFlow version requirement for Keras version 2.2.4?

I'm having trouble when using a Conv2D architecture, the GPU instance seems to crash, i.e. i can see the GPU memory fill up for a small bit and then the running processes just 'crash'.There is no error, the notebook just 'freezes'. Training dense models for example work fine. This exact same notebook with the Conv2D architecture works fine on my laptop with TensorFlow 1.12.0 & Keras 2.2.4.

I'm expecting that this has something to do with the used Keras & TensorFlow version. The GPU used is a Tesla M10 (that only supports CUDA 8.0?). The server with this M10 has Tensorflow version 1.4.1 and Keras 2.2.4.

Any insights into solving this problem would be really appreciated.

Comment: No, questions don't work like this. You should state your facts and evidence that it is a TF version problem. If it was a TF version issue, then did you try upgrading to the same version? (1.12) Did you try running code in the terminal? What does freeze means? (Maybe its swapping) Add as more information so people can help you.

Comment: The fact that your Dense model works tells that it may be possible memory consumption problem, but without any information about your models can not tell any more accurate. First check your parameter number & batch size, those tell much more, than just watching "memory fill up for a small bit" things.

Comment: Probably if you would compatibility problem, you couldn't run any model at all, at least upon my experiences.

Comment: There is no way to gather information about the 'freeze'/'crash'. These models worked before with an older version of Keras. The problem is that there is no error being displayed. So apart from describing that the GPU memory is filled up (for about 100 to 400 Mib of the 4 GB that's available) , with the processes running on the GPU then just disappearing, is all i can do. It's also not a batch size, memory size limit or transfer speed problem. It really is looking as if the GPU instance / running GPU processing are crashing about 2-3 seconds after the notebook initializes the GPUs for training

Comment: You are probably getting error messages but not seeing them (maybe in the notebook console), but since we don't know how you are running the code, we can't help further. This is why I mentioned to run it in a python script in terminal so you can see more information.

Answer (score 3):

Version compatibility between `keras` and `tensorflow` is a problem that probably anyone has faced.

As in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856613/keras-version-to-use-with-tensorflow-gpu-1-4), one combination you could use is `tensorflow-gpu 1.4` and `keras 2.0.8` . You can also check [here](https://docs.floydhub.com/guides/environments/) for more combinations too.

If you need to use `keras 2.2.4` you will have to install `tensorflow-gpu 1.11` and later, which needs `cuda 9`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll be testing this out. Couldn't find the resource you linked to, so that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Keras - Tensorflow version's compatibility is problem that developers have faced many times.

Just check Tensorflow and Keras compatibility:

[image]

Check this [link](https://docs.floydhub.com/guides/environments/) for more info